# How do I enable touchpad on boot

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

After recent update on ubuntu base 18.04.3 the touchpad on my dell machine stopped working. Luckily bluetooth was on on reboot so mouse can be used for now. But how can I enable touchpad back?